# Apache access from Tor

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, tor

I have an application running on Apache on CentOS. It has internet facing IP address. I want it to accept only anonymous connections from Tor browser. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your purpose, there are two possibilities.

You either have to [create a **hidden service**](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en):

1. Install Tor.
2. Install Apache (as you already have) and bind it to `localhost` by `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`
3. Configure hidden service in your `torrc`:

   ```
   HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
   HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
   ```

   and restart Tor. Tor then generates a new public/private keypair and a `.onion` `hostname` based on that public key. All these files can be found in the *HiddenServiceDir* specified.
4. Backup your private key if you would like to keep the `.onion` address unchanged in the future.

Or you could do the exact **opposite of [blocking](https://www.reaper-x.com/2012/05/15/how-to-block-tor-on-apache-and-nginx/)** access from Tor exit nodes.

1. Inside the desired [configuration section](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html) (`<VirtualHost>`, `<Directory>` etc.), add

   ```
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Include /etc/apache2/tor-ip.conf
   ```
2. Create `tor-ip.conf` from [dan.me.uk list of TOR exit nodes](https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/), but use `allow` instead of `deny`:

   ```
   wget -q https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/ -O - \
   | sed 's/^/allow from /g' > /etc/apache2/tor-ip.conf; \ 
   service apache2 reload
   ```

Only creating a hidden service makes your server anonymous, too. The other option only requires your users to use an anonymous Tor connection.